# Why does gnome-keyring-daemon need the public key to cache the passphrase?

Tags: gnome-keyring

I have two Arch Linux machines with virtually identical [setup](https://github.com/l0b0/root), both running `/usr/bin/gnome-keyring-daemon --daemonize --login`. They both have the same SSH secret key, but only one of them has the public key. On the host with the public key the GNOME Keyring daemon works fine - I can SSH to other machines without any prompts as expected. On the host *without* the public key it seems GNOME Keyring **ignores that I've already entered the passphrase**, and I'm prompted every time:

```
$ ls ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ls: cannot access /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
$ ssh some-host exit
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
$ ssh other-host exit
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

It also **does not list the identity**, even after entering the passphrase:

```
$ ssh-add -l
The agent has no identities.
```

After copying over the public key on a hunch I'm no longer prompted for a passphrase. After subsequently removing the public key again the symptom is back. Is there a reason for this behaviour, or is it simply a bug?

Answer (score 3):

From the GNOME Keyring documentation [SSH Agent page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring/Ssh):

> The SSH agent automatically loads files in ~/.ssh which have
>   corresponding *.pub paired files. Additional SSH keys can be manually
>   loaded and managed via the ssh-add command.

So GNOME Keyring will load `id_rsa` only if a corresponding `id_rsa.pub` exists.

You can generate one with `ssh-keygen` from the private key file

```
ssh-keygen -y -f id_rsa  > id_rsa.pub
```

If you don't want GNOME Keyring to load `id_rsa` automaticaly, you have to remove `id_rsa.pub`

I can't find any technical reasons for why this convention was chosen but it's not a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I'm not sure I agree it's not a bug, though.

Comment: fun fact, for 7 years this behavior was happening randomly to my co-workers. Today it happened to me and I finally stopped upon the doc page explaining everything.